# Importing a .GIF image into a Python Graphics Window

Tags: python, graphics, tkinter, gif

so I'm trying to import a test .GIF file into my graphics window for Python 3.x and I can't seem to get it to work. So far I have:

```
from graphics import *
from tkinter import *

def main():
    win = GraphWin ("Angry Birds!", 500,500)

    angry = PhotoImage(250,250,'angry.gif')
    angry.draw(win)
    win.mainloop()

    win.getMouse()
    win.close()
main()
```

Yes I am in a class trying to learn but we never went over this and my professor neven mentioned downloading external packages like I've seen mentioned on this website of PIL. What am I missing?